# dots in VisualStudio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Sorry for my question, but can anyone say how can I remove this dots, there is a any shortcur or other way

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Turn Off Showing Whitespace Characters in Visual Studio IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065815/how-to-turn-off-showing-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-ide)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's how to turn them on](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/11/11/how-to-show-white-space-in-visual-studio.aspx), I'd imagine you can use the same menu to disable them again.

If you don't want to click that link, it's under "Edit > Advanced > View White Space"

Answer (score 5):

Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space

or you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> keyboard shortcut.