# How do i remove this in Visual Studio? I clicked shift + ctrl + backspace

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm pretty sure that i clicked shift+ctrl+backspace on the same time (by a mistake), and then i got these arrows in Visual Studio 2012.

[image]

So now i dont know how to remove it. I hope someone can help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: you can check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065815/how-to-turn-off-showing-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-ide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the menu, Edit | Advanced, and then uncheck the view whitespace option. The keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W.