# White space is swapped with blocks in HTML in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013

[image: Indentation white spaces are swapped with those annoying blocks]

How do I get rid of all the block things?

Its far too distracting for me :(.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTRL-R, CTRL-W : Toggle showing whitespace

or under the Edit Menu:

Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space
[BTW, it also appears you are using Tabs. It's common practice to have the IDE turn Tabs into spaces (often 4), via Options.]

Source: [How to Turn Off Showing Whitespace Characters in Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065815/how-to-turn-off-showing-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-ide)

Hope it helps you =)

Comment: Thank you so much! I can now carry on with my project now, whew! :P