# How to turn off showing whitespace characters in dev-c++?

Tags: dev-c++

I pressed something, maybe in the font or the editor, and my dev-c++ started showing paragraph symbol and space symbols.

like these

> ¶¶

How can I remove that?

Comment: Maybe tell us what your IDE is?

Comment: He says Dev C++ in the title, @AntonH.  But I have added that to the tags to make it more obvious, and perhaps to attract the attention of the most appropriate people.

Comment: Copied the title from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4065815/509868); I think the code is irrelevant and ugly so removed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the editor go into "Settings -> Editor Settings", and check "Show hidden smbols" checkBox (bottom left), than push OK button.

I know this because i was searching today how to enable it XD